# AngularJS: update select view when model value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My `select` looks like

```
   <select data-ng-model="transaction.category"
            class="form-control"
            data-ng-options="category.name group by category.parent for category in categories"
            required>
    </select>
```

The `transaction` model looks like

```
$scope.transaction = {};
```

and I set values like

```
var transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.name = $scope.transaction.name;
transaction.category = $scope.transaction.category.uuid;
```

The `categories` look like

```
[  { 
name: Alcohol & Bars
parent: Food & Drink
uri: /categories/9b1e97f2-ac7d-4caf-85fc-476cd97dd6cb
uuid: 9b1e97f2-ac7d-4caf-85fc-476cd97dd6cb
 } ,  { 
name: Coffee & Tea
parent: Food & Drink
uri: /categories/cf040e77-2faa-41de-b9f7-3749a42735ac
uuid: cf040e77-2faa-41de-b9f7-3749a42735ac
 } ...
]
```

When I select the value from drop-down everything works out fine

**What is the problem then?**
There are situations when I would like to set the `category` based on some pre-populated user preference

**What do I do then?**
I do the following

```
$scope.templateSelected = undefined;
$scope.$watch('templateSelected', function () {
    if ($scope.templateSelected !== undefined) {
        $scope.transaction.category = $scope.templateSelected.category;
    }
}, true);
```

and I expect that the values on `HTML` select element will be selected. But this does not happens

**Question?**
How can I update my `select option` based on `$scope.templateSelected.category`?

**UPDATE**
The `Transaction` looks like

```
angular.module('transactionService', ['ngResource']).factory('Transaction', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/user/transactions/:transactionId',
        {transactionId: '@uuid'},
        {
            getRecent: {method: 'GET', params: {recent: true}, isArray: true},
            getForYearMonth: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true}
        });
});
```

Comment: please add the code of that Transaction class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, angular tracks selected value in `<select>` based on **object reference**.

As you set `$scope.transaction.category = $scope.templateSelected.category;`, the `$scope.transaction.category` **is not an object** in the list.

You could ask angular to do identify selected value **based on a property** using `track by category.uuid`:

```
data-ng-options="category.name group by category.parent for category in categories track by category.uuid"
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLGlRL3x6VWAcLQlbNb6?p=preview)